# How to parse a string into a comparison operator?

Tags: javascript

I implemented a method for filtering goods on the specified options. The method takes as an argument an options object that contains parameters for searching, for example: {name: "item 2", price: "<= 1000", count: "> 2"}, each of the options is optional. The method must return a filtered array with the goods. filterProductBy (options).
**I managed to filter by name. Tell me how to properly filter by the number so that the filter call looks like this:**

```
console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
name: "product 1",
count: ">1",
price: "<=1000"}));
```

"count" and "price" need to be parsed together with the comparison operator, which sets the range of the filter, here is a function that can do this, how do I implement i this func in my method, that everything would work?

```js
function parseCompOperator(oString, lhs) {
    if (oString.match("(?:<|>)=?\\d+") === null) {
        return "Invalid input";
    }

    let rator = oString.match("(?:<|>)=?")[0];
    let rhs = oString.match("\\d+")[0] * 1;

    if (rator === '>') {
        return (lhs > rhs);
    }
    else if (rator === '<') {
        return (lhs < rhs);
    }
    else if (rator === '>=') {
        return (lhs >= rhs);
    }
    else if (rator === '<=') {
        return (lhs <= rhs);
    }
}
```

**All code:**

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }
    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    //method for filtering products by specified parameters
    filterProductBy(options) {
        const optionName = options.name,
            optionCount = options.count,
            optionPrice = options.price;

        const filters = {
            byName: function (actualName, optionName) {
                return (actualName === undefined) || (actualName === optionName);
            },

            byCount: function (actualCount, optionCount) {
                return (actualCount === undefined) || (actualCount === optionCount);
            },

            byPrice: function (actualPrice, optionPrice) {
                return (actualPrice === undefined) || (actualPrice === optionPrice);
            }
    };
        return this.products.filter(
            (product) => filters.byName(product.name, optionName)
            || filters.byCount(product.count, optionCount)
            || filters.byPrice(product.price, optionPrice));
        }
}
const shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("item 2", 2, 100));
shop.addProduct(new Product("some 3", 3, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("anything 4", 4, 1000));
console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
    name: "product 1",
    count: ">1",
    price: ">=500"

}));
```

Comment: I guess `rhs` and `lhs` should be turned into `Number`s

Comment: You are doing "OR" ie `||` in `return this.products.filter` but to really filter by all 3 criterias you need to do "AND" ie. `&&`

Answer (score 5):

You could take an object with the operators as key and functions as value, like

```
var operators = {
        '===': function (a, b) { return a === b; },
        '==': function (a, b) { return a == b; },
        '<=': function (a, b) { return a <= b; },
        '>=': function (a, b) { return a >= b; },
        '<': function (a, b) { return a < b; },
        '>': function (a, b) { return a > b; }
    };
```

For use take the separated operator and the two values to compare.

You could omit the check for the operator and take a function as value, like

```
return operators[operator](leftValue, rightValue);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to tie this object to my method, so that the filters "count" and "price" work together and correctly, by the parameter that I pass: "console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
    name: "product 1",
    count: ">1",
    price: ">500"

}));"